# How to update sales_order_item in Magento 2.3 using order_id(entity_id)?

Tags: magento2, sales-order-item

In Magento 2, we can update an **order** data (a data in **sales_order**) using Magento Sales **OrderRepository** .

My questions is:

> How we can update the **sales_order_item** data (the **qty_invoiced and qty_shipped** using **order_id?**

Can anyone give me at least a way on how to do it or where to start?

Comment: You can load the model `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item` and can save the data you want.

Comment: I need to update data using order_id, can you give an example on how to implement it?

Comment: @magefms Updated the answer as per the requirement. Please check +1 for the effort this question made me to take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,
In your controller add the following code

```
<?php                                                         
 namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Orders;                       
 class SetOrders extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
 {
  protected $orderItemRepo;
  protected $resultPageFactory;
  protected $itemFactory;
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItem,
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
) {
    $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
    $this->orderItemRepo = $orderItem;
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
public function execute()
{
    try {
        //$itemId = 6;
        $orderId = 5;
        $order = $this->itemFactory->create()->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('order_id', $orderId);
        foreach ($order as $items) {
            $itemId =  $items->getItemId();
            $order = $this->orderItemRepo->get($itemId);
            $order->setAdditionalData('this is custom field');
            $order->save();
        }
        echo "success";
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        error_log($e->getMessage());
    }
}}
```

hope this may help and let me know if it works or not.

Comment: I'll check and inform you if it works

Comment: `"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setCustomField()`

Comment: wait I'll try that

Comment: Replace this $order->setCustomField(); with $order->setQtyOrdered(10);
This will update the ordered items.

Comment: the same error I got after changing

Comment: "Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to a member function setQtyOrdered()

Comment: use `$order->setData('custom_field','value');`

Comment: @magefms updated and verified and it is working fine and the problems was I used datainterface instead of item interface and which returns null. Check and let me know.

Comment: I think it worked but I need to use order_id to update the record not the item_id

Comment: @fmsthird - Can I get your email or medium to communicate?