# How to get data from sales_order_item table in magento 2

Tags: magento2, sales-order

I am new to Magento 2 and 
I want to get all data from sales_order_item table in Magento 2.

How to get that can anyone answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

**DI Method :**

Inject sales order item class in your constructor

```
 protected $itemFactory;
 public function __construct(
   ....
   \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\ItemFactory $itemFactory,
   ....
 ) {
    ....
    $this->itemFactory = $itemFactory;
    ....
 }
```

then in your function add the below code to get values from it

```
 try {    
    $order = $this->itemFactory->create()->getCollection();
    foreach ($order as $items) {
        $items->getItemId();  // similarly you can get all the values from slaes_order_item table
    }
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    error_log($e->getMessage());
}
```

For more information [Follow this answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/262798/how-to-update-sales-order-item-in-magento-2-3-using-order-identity-id/262806#262806)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Magento 2 has **service contact class** for almost most of all tables(entities).

So for this table, magento has a service contact class
[`Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface::getList($searchCriteria)`](https://devdocs.magento.com/codelinks/attributes.html#OrderItemRepositoryInterface) . Using this **interface**  for getting the all data of `sales_order_item` table data.

### Code:

```
<?php

namespace MagentostackExchange\Test\Model;


class OrderItems {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $orderItemRepository;

    public function __construct(
     \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderItemRepositoryInterface $orderItemRepository,
     \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder       
   ) {

       $this->orderItemRepository = $orderItemRepository;
       $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }
    public function getALlItemofOrderItem(){

        $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $orderItemList = $this->orderItemRepository->getList($searchCriteria);

        if($orderItemList->getTotalCount() >= 0)
        {
            foreach ($orderItemList->getItems() as $orderItem)
            {
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($orderItem->getData());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
      protected $_resource;
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->_resource = $resource;
    }
    $connection = $this->_resource->>getConnection(\Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection::DEFAULT_CONNECTION);
    $tablename = $connection->getTableName('sales_order_item');
    $query = "select * from ".$tablename;
    $connection->fetchAll($query);
```